# Ruby ternary operator if else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ternary

How would you make this ternary?

```
if @user.skill.present?
    @skill = @user.skill
else
    @skill = Skill.new
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@skill = @user.skill || Skill.new
```

If the value of @user.skill if nil, it will asign the next value( Skill.new) to @skill.

Comment: You should mention how checking for false/nil differs from using `present?`

Comment: To preserve the `present?` logic use `@skill = @user.skill.presence || Skill.new`. (`presence` returns `nil` if the object is blank)

Comment: I've used `present?` many times but had never spotted `presence` so thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use:

```
@skill = @user.skill.present? ? @user.skill : Skill.new
```

However, ternery statements aren't often an improvement in readability/maintainability. They also don't improve processing speed. And they're frowned upon in some Ruby code shops and coding styles because they're too easily abused/misused.

Using `if`/`else` is entirely appropriate in this case so don't be afraid to go that route. Consider this: If you write logic using a ternary operator, and need to add additional processing to a returned value, you'll have to switch to using regular `if`/`else` processing anyway, or you'll generate some horrible looking code that will reduce its readability.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
@user.skill.present? ? @skill = @user.skill :  @skill = Skill.new
```

Comment: Multiple assignments using `@skill =` is messy/smelly. Don't use ternary statements to branch logic, use them to return one of two possible values: `@skill = @user.skill.present? ? @user.skill : Skill.new`

Answer (score 0):

```
@skill = @user.skill.present? ? @user.skill : Skill.new
```

perhaps more readable as a two liner

```
@skill = @user.skill
if @skill.blank? @skill = Skill.new
```

Comment: `@skill = Skill.new if @skill.blank?` would be better.